# Able to use function expression before it is defined

Tags: javascript, iife, hoisting

As per hoisting function expressions cannot be invoked before they are defined. I have created a module where I am trying to access the IIFE functions before the IIFE is defined. 
According to my understanding it should have given an error saying cookieManager.setPerstistentCookie is not a function but it works fine.Why?

```
$(function(){

        var selectedContainerClassName = $('.mtaa-iml-dropdwn-options li.mtaa-iml-selected').data('parent');
        cookieManager.setPersistentCookie(cookieManager.getCookieNameByComponent('imlookingTo') , selectedContainerClassName );

});

  var cookieManager  = (function(){

        var cookieEnum = {
            imlookingTo : "selectedUIContainer"
        }

        function getPerstistentCookieExpiryTime(){
            var expiration_date = new Date();
            expiration_date.setFullYear(expiration_date.getFullYear() + 1);
            return expiration_date.toGMTString();
        }

        var setPersistentCookie = function(cname, cvalue) {
            var expires = "expires="+ getPerstistentCookieExpiryTime();
            document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
        }



        return {
            setPersistentCookie : setPersistentCookie,
            getCookieNameByComponent : getCookieNameByComponent
        }

})();
```

Comment: *Timing-wise* `$(..)` must be executed after the rest of the code, presumably because `$()` explicitly waits for the DOM to be loaded, which in your case happens to have not happened yet. (Now that's a sentence.)

Comment: You will only get an error if you try to call it before it's assigned. As long as *cookieManager* is defined (it's declared with *var*) you're fine.

Comment: A function expression is not hoisted. Only declarations are hosted.

Answer (score 2):

You've wrapped the function that refers to `cookieManager` in a jQuery "ready" handler. That code won't run until the DOM is ready, so by that time the object is defined. You're not using it before it's defined, in other words.

Comment: also cookieManager   is an IIFE

Comment: @user2181397—that's irrelevant. The RHS is evaluated and a value returned, it's not important whether that's from an IIFE or any other type of expression.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys my bad I was right about hoisting it is not working and it should not working as i interpreted.
The reason it was some how working was because I had the same script snippet copied above the `$(function(){})` snippet which I forgot to remove by mistake.
Any ways thank you for the help.